# CSS hover slide effect on navigation bar

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to implement a hover slide effect on the navigation bar using the following code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background: #2c3e50;
}
nav{
    position: relative;
    width: 590px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #34495e;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-size: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
nav a{
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
nav .animation{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    /* height: 5px; */
    top: 0;
    /* bottom: 0; */
    z-index: 0;
    background: #1abc9c;
    border-radius: 8px;
    transition: all .5s ease 0s;
}
nav a:nth-child(1){
    width: 100px;
}
nav .start-home, a:nth-child(1):hover~.animation{
    width: 100px;
    left: 0;
}
nav a:nth-child(2){
    width: 110px;
}
nav a:nth-child(2):hover~.animation{
    width: 110px;
    left: 100px;
}
nav a:nth-child(3){
    width: 100px;
}
nav a:nth-child(3):hover~.animation{
    width: 100px;
    left: 210px;
}
nav a:nth-child(4){
    width: 160px;
}
nav a:nth-child(4):hover~.animation{
    width: 160px;
    left: 310px;
}
nav a:nth-child(5){
    width: 120px;
}
nav a:nth-child(5):hover~.animation{
    width: 120px;
    left: 470px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Navbar Menu Hover Effect</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Blog</a>
      <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
      <div class="animation start-home"></div>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that I'm having some difficulty trying to adapt the code above to my navigation bar HTML structure, which looks something like this:

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>  <a href="#">Home</a> </li>
    <li>  <a href="#">About</a> </li>
    <li>  <a href="#">Blog</a> </li>
    <li>  <a href="#">Portfolio</a> </li>
    <li>  <a href="#">Contact</a> </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="animation start-home"></div>
</nav>
```

No matter how hard I try I can't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: is there problem following same structure as shown in example ?

Comment: Actually, I can't change the HTM structure, I'm using a predefined Drupal theme and this can be pretty complicated for me. All I can do is edit the css code, which I did but I wasn't able to make the animation work.

Comment: In your case I think you have 2 options: 1: learn more about editing Drupal templates and make changes at the future. 2: you hire a freelancer to do the job

Comment: So, you're saying that it is impossible to make it work without changing the HTML structure of the navigation bar ?

Comment: you have to play around CSS from example can't use as it is.

Comment: Yes of course, I understand that. I already modified the css to adapt it to my HTML but with no success. I'm trying to get a hint on how to do it the correct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `<div>` a list item i.e. `<li>` and apply animation on hover over list items.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background: #2c3e50;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  width: 590px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #34495e;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

nav a {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

nav .animation {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  /* height: 5px; */
  top: 0;
  /* bottom: 0; */
  z-index: 0;
  background: #1abc9c;
  border-radius: 8px;
  transition: all .5s ease 0s;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
}

nav li:nth-child(1) {
  width: 100px;
}

nav .start-home,
li:nth-child(1):hover~.animation {
  width: 100px;
  left: 0;
}

nav li:nth-child(2) {
  width: 110px;
}

nav li:nth-child(2):hover~.animation {
  width: 110px;
  left: 100px;
}

nav li:nth-child(3) {
  width: 100px;
}

nav li:nth-child(3):hover~.animation {
  width: 100px;
  left: 210px;
}

nav li:nth-child(4) {
  width: 160px;
}

nav li:nth-child(4):hover~.animation {
  width: 160px;
  left: 310px;
}

nav li:nth-child(5) {
  width: 120px;
}

nav li:nth-child(5):hover~.animation {
  width: 120px;
  left: 470px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Navbar Menu Hover Effect</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li> <a href="#">Home</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#">About</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Blog</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Portfolio</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Contact</a> </li>
      <li class="animation start-home"></li>
    </ul>

  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

Without changing the HTML structure, unfortunately for you, this can not be done. What make me say that is the CSS line `nav a:nth-child(x):hover ~ .animation`. With your HTML structure there is no way you can style `.animation` based on a `li` being hovered, they are not sibling. To do such thing `a` (or in your case `li`) must be on the same DOM "branch" as `.animation`

I don't know much about Drupal theme, but if you could create a "fake" item in you menu and then apply to it the `animation` class this could work. (this will change you HTML structure)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background: #2c3e50;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  width: 590px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #34495e;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

ul {
  display: contents;
}

nav li {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

nav a {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav .animation {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  /* height: 5px; */
  top: 0;
  /* bottom: 0; */
  z-index: 0;
  background: #1abc9c;
  border-radius: 8px;
  transition: all .5s ease 0s;
}

nav li:nth-child(1) {
  width: 100px;
}

nav .start-home,
li:nth-child(1):hover~.animation {
  width: 100px;
  left: 0;
}

nav li:nth-child(2) {
  width: 110px;
}

nav li:nth-child(2):hover~.animation {
  width: 110px;
  left: 100px;
}

nav li:nth-child(3) {
  width: 100px;
}

nav li:nth-child(3):hover~.animation {
  width: 100px;
  left: 210px;
}

nav li:nth-child(4) {
  width: 160px;
}

nav li:nth-child(4):hover~.animation {
  width: 160px;
  left: 310px;
}

nav li:nth-child(5) {
  width: 120px;
}

nav li:nth-child(5):hover~.animation {
  width: 120px;
  left: 470px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="#">Home</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#">About</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Blog</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Portfolio</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Contact</a> </li>
    <li class="animation start-home"></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Only changes are `<a>` replaced by `<li>` and add `display: contents` on `<ul>`

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I am able to move "<div class="animation start-home"></div>" in the HTML code. If I understood you well, you suggest to put it right before </ul> ?

Comment: you can't put before </ul> this against structure of html

Comment: @user2090879 `<div class="animation start-home"></div>` needs to be a sibling of lis. It has to be inside the `<ul>` (and of course `div` as be changed in `li`)